# Testing a web application using JMeter with keycloak authentication

Tags: oauth, jmeter, keycloak, performance-testing, openid-connect

I am trying to test my web application using JMeter which is protected by keycloak IDP. But when I try to login using the credentials the login fails saying "Please login from the client" and keycloak logs on the server says:

> 2021-04-16 11:10:05,316 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-400) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=my-realm, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=10.x.x.x, error=invalid_code

attaching the screenshot of the request I recorded using Blazemeter chrome plugin, some parameters are being sent, any idea how could we configure this?

[image: Jmeter Screenshot]

login URL :

```
https://Server_Address/auth/realms/my-realm/login-actions/authenticate?session_code=iXAkZuEnl25URJPfaSd8kaTdnwCqz5CY-pZoZUb33ns&execution=0e502d98-b482-4abc-a7a5-c31d06b1f9c2&client_id=my_client&tab_id=Fa8Ggyqw3tk
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately you won't be able to just record and successfully replay your scenario without prior [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) of the dynamic parameters.

These `execution` and `tab_id` and `session_code` guys are something you're getting as generated when you're being redirected to Keycloak instance which authenticates the user so you need to **extract** these values from the previous response and replace recorded hard-coded bullshit you get with the dynamic parameters

[image]

The easiest way to extract the values is using [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter/)

Also these parameters should go in [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), not in the request body

Demo:

[image]

Comment: I followed the same steps , but still getting the type=LOGIN_ERROR ,  error=invalid_code, Any help ??