# Registering user with JMeter + Keycloak Authorization flow

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, keycloak

I am trying to create requests with JMeter that will create user through the application. I already designed the requests but have some problems.

The hierarchy is as follow:

1. GET request to access the application and to extract: session code, execution, tab_id
   [GET request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c59on.png)
2. GET request to access the Sign Up page
   [GET request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOm84.png)
3. POST request for creating the user
   [POST request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rP4cW.png)

When I run the tests the user is not created. All the requests are passed, but the user is not created and when i check the results, some of the requests are with multiple values in the URL. For example here in the POST request I have multiple 'execution', 'client_id', 'tab_id'

[image]

The Regular Expressions Extractors are as follow:

1. session_code / session_code=(.*?)" / $1$ / 1
2. execution / execution=(.*?)" / $1$ / 1
3. tab_id / tab_id=(.*?)" / $1$ / 1

Anyone had any idea what need to be refactored in order to create an actual user ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to need to amend regular expressions like `session_code="(.*?)"`

"Duplicate" values are caused by [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) placeholders, i.e. if your regular expression doesn't have a match it has default value of `${session_code}` which is not being substituted by the respective value.

You can observe JMeter Variables with their values using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler)

If you have problems coming up with a proper regular expression you can consider using [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter/) instead, it's much easier to use (given you have "left" and "right" boundaries) and works much faster

Something similar has been [asked and answered already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67124565/testing-a-web-application-using-jmeter-with-keycloak-authentication/67126752#67126752)

Answer (score 0):

The solution I made is as follow:

1. Changed all the regular expressions to: ([^&"]*)
2. Add one more 'Regular Expression Extractor' below the second GET request 'Open Sign Up Page'

Because after we access the Sign Up Page a new 'execution' id is generated and this 'execution' id needs to be provided to the POST request in order to successfully create the user.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).